# How can we connect to a VM via anyconnect VPN in github actions

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, github-actions, vpn

I am trying to access my VM through sshpass but the problem is, We have an anyconnect VPN in the middle and that is preventing me to establish a connection to the server through github actions
How ever I can connect to that VPN in windows by using anyconnect tool.
and VPN also takes second password for more security.
Is there any way that I can connect to my VM via VPN through github actions workflow ?

Comment: did you happen to solve this?